# frequency of NSNumbers in NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, frequency, nsnumber

Hi I'm working on an app which creates an `NSArray` of `NSNumbers` based on a set of upper and lower bounds set by the user. There will be a min of 5000 randomly created numbers within these bounds...

I'm trying to work out the best way to get the frequency of each randomly generated `NSNumber` that appears in the array.

Currently I'm thinking I need to parse it through some (?) and set up a `NSDictionary` with the key as the number and the frequency it appears. However it's trying to actually do this efficiently where my mind is freezing up...

Comment: @AdamB the end result is to put the results into a scatter graph / distribution graph - to form a bell graph. With frequency on the y axis and the number on the x...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an NSCountedSet.  Just use initWithArray to create a set from your array, and it will unique the items (each value will only go in once), but will give you a count of the number of times a particular object was encountered.  Here is an example:

```
    NSArray *array = @[@1,@2,@3,@5,@7,@2,@1,@3,@9,@3,@1];
    NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
    NSLog(@"%@",set);
    for (NSNumber *num in [set allObjects]) {
        NSLog(@"Number is: %@  Count is: %d",num, [set countForObject:num] );
    }
```